# Why do I get only web service output not web service input when I create inference pipeline in ml azure?

Tags: azure

[image: no web service input!]

what I have done wrong here? web service input not created automatically. Kindly help me to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and struggled for long time.
In fact, you can simply add "web service input" manually from the left side list.
It works.

[Click this link to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmPY7.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).